# Admin side page on drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I would like to create a page in drupal with admin template. I know it can be done using module. If you know how to do this, could you please explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a look at the documentation http://drupal.org/node/361112